# How do I evaluate Perl block before subtest

Tags: perl, testing, colors, eval, block

I'm wanting to color the output of a subtest description based on the result (pass/fail) of the subtest.  Here's what I've got so far

```
sub run_subtest {
  my $desc = 'subtest description';

  subtest _construct_colored_description($desc) => sub { $passed = 1; #passed is global };
}

sub _construct_colored_description {
  my $desc = shift;
  return colored [$passed ? 'green' : 'red'], $desc;
}
```

I am `use use Term::ANSIColor` and have seen the colored output.  However, the switch from red/green is happening on the next subtest.  For instance, I have printed green tests, one fails, still prints green and the *next* test prints red.  This tells me that `$passed` and the `colored ...` is working, but the block in `subtest` is being evaluated after the `_construct_colored_description` is determining the color to output.

For my actual code, checkout my github project https://github.com/bostonaholic/test-more-behaviour

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The description is built before the test runs, not after, so you're coloring a test based on the pass/fail result of the *previous* test.

Answer (score 2):

You need to postpone evaluation of description, one solution that comes to mind is using callback for it. The idea is to return closure from `_construct_colored_description` and run it in `subtest` function:

```
my $passed = 0;

sub subtest {
    my ($desc_cb, $test_cb) = @_;
    $test_cb->();
    print $desc_cb->(),"\n";
}

sub _construct_colored_description {
    my $desc = shift;
    return sub { return $passed ? '[green]' : '[red]', $desc };
}

# testing with two subtests
my $desc = 'subtest description';
subtest _construct_colored_description($desc) => sub {
    $passed = 1;
};

$desc = 'subtest description2';
subtest _construct_colored_description($desc) => sub {
    $passed = 0;
};
```

Gives:

```
[green]subtest description
[red]subtest description2
```

Comment: @Matthew Boston - glad I could help.

Comment: Actually, this didn't quite work.  the subroutine `subtest` is part of `Test::More` and overwriting it yielded different results in the test behavior.  I would prefer to use `subtest` because it allows me to have multiple ok's in a block but only count as a single test.